# Are there tools that implement the Code First mantra for existing schemas?

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, database-design, code-first

I really like the Entity Framework Code First idea because I can rapidly prototype new projects, but right now I'm dealing with a database that already exists.

We have many databases with the same schema. At the moment, if we start new projects,
we need to copy the database to to a new server. How can I 'save' us from having to do this step manually?

I think I have two options:

1. Copy the Database as before and generate a ADO.NET Entity Data Model with the Wizard
2. Write the code first and map that to the database schema, and let Code First generate the database if it doesn't exist.

Is there a tool that does this?

Comment: This any use for you: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/02/24/generating-ef-code-first-model-classes-from-an-existing-database.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jon Galloway [has the solution on his blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/02/24/generating-ef-code-first-model-classes-from-an-existing-database.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I am working on database context initializer which will notify webmaster if model and db schema are out of sync and will show what differs. This can by useful for developers who prefer to have complete control both over code-first model and database schema. Check it out:

https://github.com/rialib/efextensions